# How to download file in memory and then upload it to somewhere else

Tags: javascript

I would like to do create a tempermonkey script that would download a file on a site without bothering the user with saving it on the disk. So the file would be stored in a variable, which the script would be able to use to upload that file to my remote server.

Is it possible to do in browser javascript?

- Diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: yes, it is possible to do with a grease/tampermonkey script

Comment: But why even pass through the user's machine? You can just get the link and download directly from your server

Comment: @aviya.developer - it's a good point, why use someone else browser to get data from someone elses website

Comment: Might require the user to be logged in to download the file.

Comment: @NickSlash you are correct. The file must be downloaded under authenticated user when he performs an action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to download the file as a blob using fetch:

```
async function upload() {
  const res = await fetch('https://example.com/download-endpoint')
  const blob = await res.blob()

  fetch('https://example.com/upload-endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': blob.type
    },
    body: blob
  })
}
```

Comment: this is pretty simple, straightforward answer. Easy to understand. Thank you